# How do I change the default workbook for an Excel DSN?

Tags: c++, excel, windows, dsn

I am trying to change the default workbook used by my Excel DSN using the following code:

```
    std::string DSNConfig;
    DSNConfig = "DSN=Excel Files";
    DSNConfig += '\0';
    DSNConfig += "DBQ=";
    DSNConfig += outputFile;
    DSNConfig += '\0';
    DSNConfig += '\0';

    if (!::SQLConfigDataSource(NULL, ODBC_CONFIG_DSN, "Excel", DSNConfig.c_str())) {
        WORD iError, cbErrorMsg;
        DWORD fErrorCode;
        char ErrorMsg[1000];
        iError = 1;
        SQLInstallerError(iError, &fErrorCode, ErrorMsg, sizeof(ErrorMsg), &cbErrorMsg);
        throw WplException(Message(ErrorMsg));
    }
```

Every time I get an error message "Component not found in the registry" but the User DSN does exist, I can see it in the DSN manager.

Clearly I am missing something, can anyone see what?

Answer (score 3):

> DSNConfig += "\0";

Doesn't do what you think it does.

I assume you are trying to append a `'\0'` character to the `std::string`.  However, this will append an empty string. `std::string::operator +=(const char *)` will stop at the *first* NUL character it encounters.

The fix is:

```
DSNConfig += '\0';
```

Comment: Good spot, thanks (I have updated the code in the question).  I still have the error though :-(

Comment: @Stefan Damn!  I'm afraid I know nothing about DSNs, and just spotted the C++ error.  As such, I think this answer is now wrong.

Comment: Well it certainly helped even if it didn't completely solve the issue!